# Прямая речь с абзаца

Tags: грамотная-речь, оформление-текста, абзац

Прямая речь пишется с абзаца. Абзац подразумевает отступ от края строки, но я не помню, чтобы в книгах прямая речь давалась с красной строки. Отсюда вопрос: по правилам нужно выделять прямую речь красной строкой или нет? Достоверных источников не нашла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если прямая речь оформляется не в строку, а с абзаца, перед ней ставится абзацный отступ и тире. Абзацный отступ согласно учебникам по пунктуации ОБЯЗАТЕЛЕН. Не может что-то начинаться с абзаца без абзацного отступа.

Абзац — это по определению отступ вправо в начале первой строки какой-либо части текста или часть текста между двумя такими отступами. Абзацев без отступов не бывает.

Во всех учебниках в разделе "Прямая речь" соответствующие примеры набраны с отступами (в том числе и в [Полном академическом справочнике:](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=138#pp138).  )

Но иногда стиль издания вообще не подразумевает абзацные отступы. Когда весь текст набран без абзацных отступов (но деление текста на части есть), мы говорим, что таков стиль издания, и не ставим их, оформляя прямую речь. Если же мы видим, что отступы в тексте есть, они обязательны и перед прямой речью.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно прямая речь выделяется в тексте кавычками либо дается отдельным абзацем, в начале которого ставится тире. Это значит, что прямая речь не всегда выделяется абзацем.См.:[Академический справочник од редакцией Лопатрина](http://orthographia.ru/)

Дополнение с сказанному:АБЗАЦ — в первоначальном значении своем — то же, что и красная строка.Но А. означает и отрывок письменной речи, заключенный между красными строками. Так как употребление абзаца не предусматривается никакими строго установленными правилами, то и в обычном его употреблении проявляется художественное намерение автора и здесь его применение в значительной мере субъективно.Можете прочитать здесь:[Литературная энциклопедия](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_literature/16/%D0%90%D0%B1%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86)

Comment: Благодарю, но, возможно, я неверно сформулировала вопрос. Меня интересует, нужно ли выделять прямую речь, которая начинается с абзаца и тире, красной строкой.

Comment: Это не прямая речь, это диалог: каждая реплика с нового абзаца, про красную строку речи нет, тире ставится в начале абзаца без отступа, если нет нужды как-то выделить эту часть текста.

Comment: Любая реплика диалога называется прямой речью. Это именно прямая речь. Абзац и красная строка - это одно и тоже. Абзац по определению подразумевает отступ.